# Zend Framework 2 Translating the text of the radio buttons

Tags: forms, radio-button, zend-framework2, zend-translate

I´m developing an application using Zend Framework 2 and I need to translate the text of the radio buttons ("Show", "Hide") that I´ve created in my form:

```
    //within the Form

    public function addRadioButtons ()
        {
            $isPublicRadioButtons = new Element\Radio('isPublic');
            $isPublicRadioButtons->setAttribute('id', 'isPublic')
                    ->setAttribute('value', '0')
                    ->setValueOptions(array(
                        '0' => 'Show',
                        '1' => 'Hide',
                    ));

            $this->add($isPublicRadioButtons);
        }
```

What do I have to do in the view side to be able to translate them?

I know that to render translations to the views I need to use $this→translate() view helper. So within the view I´ll have to somehow call the text of the radio buttons..

```
//Whithin the view

echo $this->translate($someHowCallTheTextOfRadioButton('isPublic') , $textDomain, $locale);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [FormLabel](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.view.helpers.html#formlabel) section to read about translating labels in zend framework 2. I think that most important thing to remember is:

> If you have a translator in the Service Manager under the key,
>   ‘translator’, the view helper plugin manager will automatically attach
>   the translator to the FormLabel view helper. See
>   Zend\View\HelperPluginManager::injectTranslator() for more
>   information.

How to properly setup translator you have in [ZendSkeletonApplication](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php)

Answer (score 0):

In your view you can do something like this:

$this->formRadio()->setTranslatorTextDomain('textdomainhere');

Answer (score 0):

You can have your form implement the TranslatorAwareInterface and, if you are using PHP 5.4+, have it use the TranslatorAwareTrait (otherwise you simply have to implement the interface yourself). You can now inject a translator instance into your form, e.g. in the form's factory. Then you can translate the labels as follows:

```
//within the Form

public function addRadioButtons ()
    {
        $isPublicRadioButtons = new Element\Radio('isPublic');
        $isPublicRadioButtons->setAttribute('id', 'isPublic')
                ->setAttribute('value', '0')
                ->setValueOptions(array(
                    '0' => $this->getTranslator()->translate('Show'),
                    '1' => $this->getTranslator()->translate('Hide'),
                ));

        $this->add($isPublicRadioButtons);
    }
```